# How to make a minimized UE4 application continue to run in the background or minimized?

Tags: windows, unreal-engine4

I am essentially trying to create something like a launcher for an Unreal application. The expected behavior that I was looking for is that when I launch an application the launcher would minimize or hide in the background and then whenever you close the application the launcher would then be restored.

I can successfully get the launcher to launch the other app and minimize itself but, for some reason my method for re-maximizing it doesn't seem to work. However, I was able to get it to work if I keep the app on screen(& not in focus) but, at a small size. It just seems that minimizing or hiding the app causes this method not to work

Essentially, I am using `FPlatformProcess::CreateProc` and grabbing the `processID` and then listening to see if the application is running. If it quits running then I (try to) restore the window.

My guess is there is something happening that is most likely pausing the app for some reason. I should also note that I overrode the `UGameViewportClient` class so that it doesn't pause the game even if it loses focus and that doesn't seem to work either.

I could possibly modify some code on the other application but, I want to keep that at a minimum. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a hold of one of the Engine developers with my question. Essentially, there are two options for doing something like this. First, you can use the [MessageBus](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Messaging/IMessageBus/index.html) class and establish a connection between the two game instances. The drawback to this method however, is that it isn't really possible to detect crashes and things of that nature.

The second method (the approach I took) is to create a watchdog program in something like Visual Basic that you can use to set up a listener to a process exiting. This also allows you to set up other things like listening for application crashes or sending logs to developers.